# Non-Latin character encoding in Firefox

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, fonts, special-characters

I installed Lubuntu 15.04 Vivid last week, making the first step away from Windows for me.

I am running Firefox 38.0 (Mozilla Fifefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0). In Windows 7, when I loaded pages with non-Latin/special characters like Japanese Kanji and Korean, they were displayed correctly, but now Firefox seems to have a problem displaying them; they appear like boxes with letters and numbers in them.

The only advice I've found was to change the **Settings > content > Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above** to **true**, but that was already set.

What else can I try?

Comment: Installing the packages from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Installing_Japanese_character_sets#Debian_GNU.2FLinux_and_Ubuntu fixed the problem for Japanese, but in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language this page many Korean characters still do not appear correctly.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the package `ubuntustudio-font-meta` through

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-font-meta
```

everything seems to work fine. The Japanese and the Korean characters are displaying correctly, as well as the Chinese, Vietnamese and IPA.

Wikipedia mentions some language support packages for Debian/Ubuntu [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Multilingual_support_%28East_Asian%29#Debian-based_GNU.2FLinux).